# SOAP4R SOAPDateTime format based on GMT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, soap4r

App uses SOAP4r for consuming API/SOAP

But SOAP::SOAPTimeFormat is returning 
2015-11-15T16:59:521468.7999999999999545-04:00

```
chkout.add('purchasedDt ', SOAP::SOAPDateTime.new(basket.purchase_Date))
```

Using strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') is giving the following

```
chkout.add('purchasedDt ', SOAP::SOAPDateTime.new(basket.purchase_Date.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')))
```

2015-11-15T16:59:52Z

What App needs is
2015-11-15 16:59:52 -0400
Please advise ...need the format in 
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss-/+gmt

-Fransis

Answer (score 2):

A simple change in your strftime and you can find out more in the doc for [Time#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
basket.purchase_Date.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %z')
=> "2016-04-26 22:48 -0400"
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your applicaton accepts the iso8601 format. You can use [`Time#xmlschema`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-xmlschema) as a shortcut to generate iso8601 compatible strings:

```
basket.purchase_Date.xmlschema
#=> "2015-11-15T16:59:52-04:00"
```

Just change this line in your example:

```
chkout.add('purchasedDt ', SOAP::SOAPDateTime.new(basket.purchase_Date.xmlschema))
```

Comment: From the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-xmlschema): *If self is a UTC time, Z is used as TZD. [+-]hh:mm is used otherwise.* It seems like your timestamp is already UTC. Can you please call `.zone` on your timestamp? That returns the timezone of the timestamp. I would like to understand the conflict between the behavior and the `-04:00` part in your post.

Comment: I used SOAPString and .zone ..it shows "Eastern Daylight Time" in the SoapUI.                              **chkout.add('purchasedDt',SOAP::SOAPString.new(referral.created_at.zone))**